# Define is not recognized by IntelliSense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-preprocessor, intellisense

I am getting a weird error where a define macro is not recognized by visual studio. It underlines the `INTERFACE__` macro as well as all member functions as they are "outside a class definition". Other classes using the `INTERFACE__` macro are fine. It's just for this one class which seems like an IntelliSense glitch.

**Macro**

```
#ifndef MACRO_H
#define MACRO_H

#include "Environment.h"

#define INTERFACE__ struct
#endif
```

**Logger**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include "LogLevel.h"
#include "Macro.h"

namespace se {

    INTERFACE__ Logger {

        Logger() { }
        virtual ~Logger() { }

        virtual void log(const LogLevel level, const std::string& text) = 0;
        virtual void severe(const std::string& text) = 0;
        virtual void warning(const std::string& text) = 0;
        virtual void info(const std::string& text) = 0;
        virtual void exception(const std::string& text, std::exception exception) = 0;
    };
}
#endif
```

Comment: Is it possible that `MACRO_H` is already defined at some point when your `#include "Macro.h"? The naming choice seems dangerous.

Comment: Don't use macros. Define struct. Less problem for you and for other people. I think you can replace guard macro by `#pragma once`. Macro is evil and pain.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with [`Environment.h`](http://codepad.org/SgP7LSC9) and [`a.cpp`](http://codepad.org/2A7LkUpN). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Firstly: changing the include guard does not help
Secondly pragma once is not an option due to build configurations.
And lack of reproducability kind of supports my guess on a glitch... :/

Comment: Is it IntelliSense problem or your program doesn't compile?

Comment: It does compile. But intellisense does not work on this class which is a pain.

Comment: OMG, it is not a problem at all. IntelliSense never works correctly. Just relax and write code.

Comment: Ugh, I guess I'm being too perfectionistic about it...
Anyway thanks

Comment: And note that having an identifier with two consequitive underscores is illegal in C++.

Comment: If it compiles fine and it is only an IntelliSense problem, then make sure to make this fact very clear in the question. It makes the question easier to identify and will likely generate better answers (or any answers at all).

Comment: P.S.: I've added the appropriate tag to the question.